# C# deserialize considering GraphQL __typename

Tags: c#, json, graphql, json-deserialization

I have a complex json from GraphQL call, and it contains property `__typename` in different levels to specify what classes should be used to deserialize.

By default, `System.Text.json` deserialize does not support `__typename` and it tries to deserialize into the abstract class instead of the inherited classes (e.g. it tries to deserialize into abstract `Animal` instead of `Dog`, `Cat`, `Horse`, etc.).

Please note that different `__typename` show in the structure not just in root.

What deserializer/converter should I use that will take into consideration the `__typename`s to properly identify what classes should be used?

I don't think I need to implement anything custom because `__typename` is GraphQL standard to indicate type to be used.